# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and $_GET

Tags: php

How do I pass a destination variable in a URL which contains OTHER variables from last page?

Basically, when I'm on `index.php?year=2014&month=3` and when i click edit.php link  I want it to remember the (`index.php?year=2014&month=3`) so it returns me back there after editing... I placed this in `$destination` but its conflicting with my URL variables...

`SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns: `index.php?year=2014&month=3`

my php code:

```
$destination = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$edit_url = "edit.php?id=$id&proj=$proj&t=$t&year=$year&month=$month&day=$day&destination=$destination";
```

when I click the edit link:
`http://www.site.com/edit.php?id=5&proj=3&t=1&year=2014&month=4&day=13&destination=/index.php?year=2014&month=3`

once it takes me to `edit.php` I noticed its not capturing the hidden input `&month=3`
in source it shows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="destination" value="/index.php?year=2014">
```

it should be showing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="destination" value="/index.php?year=2014&month=3">
```

I know it's because of the `&` sign which is causing this...is it possible to make `url.php?blah=1&destination=/page.php?var=1&var=2` ??? If so, can someone tell me how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `urlencode()` to encode `$destination` before you add it to the URL.

Basically, you are adding a value to a URL with a `&` in it which is a special character used for other purposes in a URL. The server is seeing this character and is cutting the value short. By encoding it, you should get the correct value.

You can use `urldecode()` to return the value back to normal later on.

Comment: beautiful. thank you! will accept in a few minutes when the site lets me.